# "Benehmen" and "Verhalten"

Tags: difference, noun

What is the difference between *Verhalten* and *Benehmen*?

> 1. Sein Verhalten meinen Eltern gegenüber ist schön.
> 2. Mein Benehmen in der Deutschklasse war sehr gut.

Comment: IMHO, *schön* paßt weder zu *Verhalten* noch zu *Benehmen*. Passen würde zum Beispiel *einwandfrei*, *ohne Tadel*, *respektvoll*, *angemessen*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me, *Benehmen* has a focus on personal characteristics and manners. When it comes to humans and pets, the words are used as synonyms. *Verhalten* can also be used to address characteristics of technical objects:

> Das Verhalten des Autos im Gelände ist ausgezeichnet.

*Benehmen* can’t be used here.

Comment: Good point. We could say that "Benehmen" is "Verhalten" controlled by will.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the answer of @lejonet I'd like to point out that *Benehmen* is somewhat close to the idea of *manners*.

> Er hat kein Benehmen.
>
> He has no manners.

Also, *benehmen* bei itself is positive.

> Benimm dich!
>
> Behave.

while *Verhalten* is just a way of behaving.

> Verhalte dich!

makes no sense. People would be asking "How?". It's the same as if I were to say:

> Behave in some way!

that would have people asking "What way?"

Comment: I've never heard the term "Verhalte dich!", because you always "behave [in some way]" by definition. So you could only ask s.o. to behave differently: "Verhalte dich ruhig!" ~ "Stay Calm!" or "Er verhält sich immer so zurückweisend." ~ "He's always [behaving] so repudiative."

Comment: @dog ... That's what I was trying to convey actually. However, there is a use "Ich muss mich dazu verhalten." without a direct indication how.

Comment: @dog In English, you can use "behave" by itself in some contexts, as the one mentioned by Emanuel: "Behave yourself!". In this example, it implicitly means "mind your behavior" , "behave nicely". It was very helpful thay Emanuel mentioned that "benehmen" should be the verb used in this case.